# Can We Have Different Wallpapers For Each Workspace under Gnome?

Tags: gnome, wallpaper, workspaces

I was wondering whether we can have different wallpapers in each workspace of a Linux distro using Gnome. Googled it. Solutions I found require desktop effects to be enabled. My laptop can't take up that much load. So I wanted to know if their's a way to do so without enabling any effects.

[**note**] My distro is Fedora 14.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is [not without applying patches](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48004).

But you could use a different window manager / desktop environment. Enlightenment, for example, supports this feature.

Comment: Woa, dated back to 2001! I would have thought this lies in some hidden dot files...

Comment: Thanks. Won't prefer switching DE. Especially when GNOME 3 is round the corner. :)

Answer (score 4):

Answer to a very old question if anyone still wondering: Yes, you can.

Using a Gnome extension called [**Walkpaper**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1200/walkpaper/). Install, open its preferences/options, assign wallpaper to each workspace and done.

Answer (score 0):

Just a vague workaround proposition:

A script/fonction that would:

1. change the active workspace (`wmctrl`?)
2. change the background (`display -root`?)

Comment: Do you know if this has a chance of working at all? Did you try it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Gnome doesn't have this feature by default.

However I use a Python software called Wallpapoz.

It's not fast. It takes some time for the wallpaper to change.

http://vajrasky.wordpress.com/wallpapoz

https://vajrasky.wordpress.com/